# How compute the probability of 12 samples with a normal

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim N(\mu = 580 mg/kg,\sigma = 68 mg/kg)$, wich measure the quantity of water in a tree. What's the probability that 12 random samples, at least 5 of **this samples** have 628 mg/kg of water or more?

I tried with a binomial, but the probability is so small... Anyone can help me?

EDIT: I write $\hat{X} \sim Binomial(n = 12, p = 0.2401)$ where $p = P(X \geq 628)$ and $\hat{X}$ is the number of trees with 628 mg/kg of water of more. Then

$$
P(Y \geq 5) = 0.13788650306
$$
I did the last step with a binomial calculator.

Comment: Do you mean the **given** 12 samples, at least 5, .... (the bold word was missing)

Comment: Also, yea, binomial is the way to go. What do you mean by the probability is so small? Can you show your work please. However, without looking at your work, I dare hazard a guess that you did not compute “$\ge 5$“ but only computed “$=5$“.

Comment: I added my work

Comment: You'll want to show your work on how you calculated $p=0.2401$

Comment: with a calculator too

Comment: Everything looks correct. I have checked with a calculator. What’s wrong?